# SOAP Request / Response Comparison Tool

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

Typically an enterprise application consumes a number of webservices. It is likely that some of these webservices that are being consumed will be upgraded to a new version every month. Before consuming the new webservice , the consumer must do a thorough analysis of changes between old service and new service which will form the basis of impact assessment.

I have come across tools that compare the WSDL , however some of the services that the application consumes could be huge and the WSDL might have more than say 50 operations. The consuming application might be using say 10 operations. By using WSDL comparator , it could be a bit tedious to identify if a modified element is part of a any of the operations consumed. In order to do such an analysis, I usually generate the request and response using SOAP UI for each operation and use text comparison tools to identify the difference.

Is there a tool available for performing of operation-wise comparison when 2 WSDLs are provided as input?

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-messages.html ?

Comment: can I split the bounty for all the 3 responses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL is eventually an **XML document**. The **[XmlUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)** can come very handy in this case. Its essentially a utility for unit testing the XML application which make heavy use of XML. In the most trivialized for, it has a `Diff` class which actually compares the XML as follows:

```
Diff myDiff = new Diff("</Original>", "</Modified>");
```

But as I said, this is very trivialized. Please explore this for more details.

Also there is [XML diff utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17604/adx_j_diff.htm) from Oracle.

Not sure if you the operation-wise comparison is possible or not.

Comment: Yes , that was the route that I was going for. Fetching the operationwise request and response and doing a comparison. But just wanted to check if there is anything out of the box available so that I need not re-invent the wheel. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Service Registry

It sounds like you are describing service governance. Some of the functionality you are describing can be provided by a registry above the functions of finding and publishing services.

- http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/
- http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/wsrr/

Comment: Thanks for your response Andy! We aren't using any service registry in our organization. I am looking for a tool that would take 2 wsdls as input and list the differences in request / response of matching operations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to generate classes from wsdl files using [Eclipse WSDL2Java plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/download.html%E2%80%8E) instead of generating each operation request and response, in my idea it can facilitate your work. Then compare the new classes with old ones using [Devart Code Compare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/). Am i right?

Comment: But is there no out of the box tool available to do this? Also I would like to see the xml differences displayed , so might have to marshall the code again in this case I guess.

Comment: @Punter Vicky, My guess for existence of out of the box tool is no, but Devart Code Compare also supports XML for comparison.